# Unusual icons/program on taskbar cannot remove

Tags: uninstall, icons, taskbar

The icons are three circles; a circle with an arrow inside, a red circle with a 9 inside and a white circle with an a inside.
Since this appeared on the task bar all my programs and open pages disappear when I shrink them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from this you're using the Mate environment. correct me if i'm wrong.

this is seemingly a widget area  or widget that's been created.

Normally if you right click on it it will bring up the widget's options and you'll be able to delete it :
does your ubuntu look like this: 
[image: deleting a widget]

or like this? :

[image: ubuntu unity]

thus restoring the full length of the tasks in the taskbar.

Comment: Nothing happens when I right click.

Comment: try instead of shrinking it making it bigger then right-cick on the empty space instead.
which version of ubuntu (or is it even ubuntu) are you using? open up settings then about and tell me the distro version and number it should look something like this "ubuntu 17.04 - Ubuntu Zesty Zapus 64bit "

Comment: Apologies,  it's Ubuntu 16.5

Comment: ubuntu 16.5 doesn't exist. perhaps you mean 16.04?
are you using the default Desktop Environment or another such as mate I screencaped above?